# Jquery dialog close when session timeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am working with an ASP.NET MVC4 application which loads lot of jQuery dialogs with partial views in div on click events. I have come across an issue when the session times out, the application login page loads within the jQuery Dialog Popup.

Is there any way to close the jQuery Dialog popup when the session has timed out so that they are returned to the actual application login page to re-authenticate?

**This is my Actionresult**

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    try
    {
        // Do something
    }
    catch { throw; }
    finally
    {

    }
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your login page code detect if the session is stale, if so return something to reload the whole page in the browser.

If you are using iframes, you can just return JS that adds the meta refresh to the page...

```
<script>
    $(parent.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).append('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">');
</script>
```

If you are AJAXing directly into a div, you can just return the meta refresh tag and it should reload the page...

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">
```

Comment: How can I return <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0"> from controller actionresult?

Comment: No idea mate but my guess is that there will be quite a few ways. Have a Google, but I would approach it as maybe even make a new view to handle just this, or wrap the login view in a conditional looking at a variable in the ViewBag.